# Magento 1.9 : How to add product with discount automatically in the shopping cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, rules, automation

Hope you're all doing well.

I need some guidance in how or if some tool already exist for this:

If an specific product enters the shopping cart, automatically one other specific product appears in the cart, but with discount.

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare event observers in config.xml :

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>cartProductAddAfter</method>
            </custommodule>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <checkout_cart_product_update_after>
        <observers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>cartProductUpdateAfter</method>
            </custommodule>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
</events>
```

Then create observer file in your module :

```
class Vendor_Custommodule_Model_Observer 
{
    /* If you'd like to do the same while updating the shopping cart*/
    public function cartProductUpdateAfter($observer)
    {
        $this->cartProductAddAfter($observer);
    }

    public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $currentItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $currentItem->getQuote();
        $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();

        /* Detect Product ID and Qty programmatically */
        $idToAdd = "ANY PRODUCT ID";
        $qty = 1;

        $productToAdd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        /* @var $productToAdd Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $productToAdd->load($idToAdd);

        $this->_addProductToCart($productToAdd, $qty);
        //put code apply code discount here
    }

    protected function _addProductToCart($product, $qty)
    {
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        /* @var $cart Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart */
        if ($product->getId()) {
            $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then put your code for apply discount after line

```
$this->_addProductToCart($productToAdd, $qty);
```

Hope it helps !